# AWS Redshift query optimisation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-redshift, databricks

Trying to insert data into `redshift` using `pyspark` dataframe `write` function

Is there a better way to write the `postActions` query?

The `USING` keyword in the `postActions` part is a bit confusing and i believe it causes performance issues as well.

DDL `sortkey` is `updatekey`

trying to delete some rows from `mastertable` with `staging` as reference, after writing the data from dataframe( using `postActions` )

```
def updatemaster_table(mastertable, dataframe,updatekey):

    staging = mastertable+'_staging'

    postActions = f"""
        DELETE FROM {mastertable} USING {staging} WHERE {mastertable}.{updatekey} = {staging}.{updatekey};
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {staging}
    """

    dataframe.write \
        .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift") \
        .option("url",  REDSHIFT_JDBC_URL) \
        .option("dbtable", staging) \
        .option("extracopyoptions", EXTRACOPYOPTIONS) \
        .option("postactions", postActions) \
        .option("forward_spark_s3_credentials", "true") \
        .option("tempdir", "s3a://"+S3_BUCKET+"/tempdir") \
        .mode("append") \
        .save()
```

Comment: The SQL matters, but it's not enough by itself to answer the question, as the  DDL of the tables involved matters as well.  What are the sorting orders of those tables, and are they vacuumed?

Comment: Can you describe the process you are doing a little better?  It looks like you are adding data to a table then removing some rows based on the same added data.  Do I have this right?  USING isn't a problem by itself but if you are only deleting rows in part of the table (like Max says sortkey matters) then you can speed things us with an additional WHERE clause.

Comment: @MaxGanzII : i have edited the question to add more info

Comment: @BillWeiner : You got it right, i am adding data first, then removing some rows based on the same added data. More like an `upsert`

Comment: First question - how do you know which rows are old and which are new (and should be kept)? But that's not the optimization question.  If the table being "upserted" to is very large, the DELETE command is looking through it entirely to find matches which can be slow.  If you only need to look at a portion of the fact table for possible deletes then adding an additional WHERE clause *MAY* make this restriction can greatly improve the DELETE performance.   The improvement will be based on table structure and sort keys.